# Real time color changing of an object

Tags: makehuman, color-management

I want to develop a human model where the segments of human body lets say human lower arm changes its color.
I am new to blender any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to assign a separate material to that body part, then animate that material color over time, with keyframes

Here is an example of how to do this: the monkey head has a ase blue color, but I assigned a different (grey) material to one ear.

Then at frame 1 I inserted a key frame for the color (press <kbd>I</kbd> over the diffuse grey slot), and at frame 80 I changed the color to red, and inserted another keyframe.

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance.This is really helpful.
Please if you could also assist me in changing the color in real time... say changing according to room temperature values or any other real time varying quantity sent as an input to blender.